# Algorithm to find path in continuous space

Tags: algorithm

I have a big map with ( 20000 x 20000 ) and I have occasionally obstacles with shape of polygon ( from 4 to 20 edges ). How to find path between two points, which algorithm is appropriate to use for this to be reasonably quick ?
( At the moment I am splitting map to cells and using A* algorithm to find path but smoothness is not good because it is passing from center of one cell to another and for more distant start / end pair is slow ).
Which algorithm can you suggest, no need implementation just suggestion.

Comment: You could use a non-uniform grid which has more density closer to complex obstacles, in a divide-and-conquer sort of way.  Or look in to how a navmesh is implemented, such as with Unity3d

Comment: How many polygons are we talking about?

Comment: @cobarzan hundreds of polygons, depends of level

Comment: Then you can just define a graph having as vertices the corners of your polygons (plus your start and target) and as edges the all pairs of vertices that can "see" each other. Then run A* or Dijkstra on this graph. Not sure how to implement efficiently the "see" thing, but in case you have multiple queries (start, target) you only need to determine the "see" thing once for the polygon corners. And since the number of polygons is small, you will get a graph that is considerably smaller.

Comment: There must be some sort of tree structure that is not expensive to build and to answer to queries like: does this segment intersect any segment in the tree structure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A* is indeed the correct algorithm to be using for this task. This is still a shortest path problem; your issues with "smoothness" and efficiency likely come from the way you are *dividing your map into nodes on a graph*, rather than the technique you are using to *traverse* them.

In order to get finer control over the way your actors move across the map and have them find paths quickly, you may wish to experiment with [navigation meshes or waypoints](http://theory.stanford.edu/~amitp/GameProgramming/MapRepresentations.html). The idea is that, rather than doing A* on a graph with many, many nodes, you instead find ways to do it on much less complex graphs, filtering through a hierarchy of very broad paths to finer details of those paths -- this greatly reduces the time to complete the task, because even efficient implementations of the shortest path problem still have high computational complexity.